# PDO Error Handling, is this ok?

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling

I use PDO with try and catch so i can catch the error into a user defined function. I want to know if this method is acceptable.

**The Try and Catch:**

```
Try
{

...

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Proccess error
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $line = $e->getLine();
    $code = $e->getCode();

    handle_error($msg, $timestamp, $line, $code);
    die("oops! It's look like we got an error here! Try Again!");
}
```

**The error handling function:**

```
function handle_error($msg, $timestamp, $line, $code) {

    $file = 'errorlog.txt';
    $data = "$timestamp // Error Message: $msg | Error Code: $code | Error Line: $line \n";
    file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);

    return;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean if this ok? The way I see it, it's up to you the way you want to handle your errors.

Comment: If it works, satisfies your intentions and passes all code design requirements - it's ok. If not - it's not ok.

Comment: I mean, this is safe enough? it's a decent error handling for a real website or i need to do something else?

Comment: Well, it does not expose any obvious vulnerability. You are just writing to a text file. Where that file is located? Is it available to access directly through a web server?

Comment: Well i'm still testing. I want to place this error log in some place like /var/logs/ in the server.

Comment: Why not just use [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: Because i want to give the errors a diferent format as seen in that example.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of that could wrong is that if by some chance a user finds out a way to trigger PDO errors then he can basically DDoS the system by triggering it over and over again and filling up your harddrive with the same error. Not to mention it can use up all your disk I/O bandwidth (when exploiting it).

Then again, Apache does similar logging and I haven't heard of HDDs being filled up even while under DDoS attacks.

Comment: No, I actually take that back. Apache does about the same logging and you don't actually fill up entire HDDs even under DDoS. Logging that much shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Nice then, i'll wait for more comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the log writing by changing your code similar to this

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
$my_error = "Failed;" . $e;
error_log(print_r($my_error,TRUE));
}
```